# why tcp counts bytes not packets?

Tags: tcp

considering [tcp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) it uses 32bits to count bytes as Sequence number or Acknowledgment number
why it doesn't count packets ?

im building a protocol like tcp over udp and want to know why tcp uses bytes instead of counting packets

Comment: TCP is a byte stream not a sequence of messages (packets). When data are lost they will be resent in the optimal way, no matter if these were separate packets before or not. Does this answer your question? [How does TCP packet numbering make it easier for retransmission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022971/how-does-tcp-packet-numbering-make-it-easier-for-retransmission)

Comment: hmm
considering udp provides datagram integrity with checksum i'll probably can get away with using 1 byte as msg seq by counting packets

Comment: UDP checksum does not provide integrity, it provides rudimentary error detection only. For actual integrity you need something longer and more complex than a simple CRC.